# Display text as a hyperlink in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to cast text as a hyperlink. As I can cast XML so that when I tap it opens an XML file [(XML example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUyKs.png), when I write 'SELECT smth' I get a value with the text I set and when I tap it opens the link.

[I need it to look like this hyperlink or the MS Word example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Fyh.png). Is this somehow possible to do it ONLY with SQL?

Comment: Not possible (unless any addin exists to do it). SSMS has a [built in web browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-web-browser?view=sql-server-ver16) but there is nothing you can do to return hyperlinks in the grid in a way that they will open in it.

Comment: Um, why? That's a function of SSMS, why would you want to display a hyperlink there?

Comment: Converting a URL into a (clickable) *link* is a presentation matter, not a SQL (Server) matter.

Comment: In SQL Server, you can't directly create hyperlinks within the result set of a query. SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) or any other SQL client typically doesn't support rendering hyperlinks directly in query results.

Comment: the closest i guess is you can create an external tool so when you select over some text and activate the tool, it can open a web browser with that link as text. But you can probably whip up a simple WinForm application that can replicate what you want to do in a couple of hours

Comment: The question is unclear. Displaying URLs is the job of client applications. Are you asking how to retrieve the page a URL points to perhaps?